# Guarding init modifications for both emacs23 and emacs24?

Tags: emacs, macros

I have some emacs commands cribbed away and copy/paste them into `~/.emacs` when needed.

I want to add a code-folding macro, but the macro appears to be different for emacs23 and emacs24. The next two requirements come from Stack Overflow's [How to permanently enable the hs-minor-mode in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12763566).

For emacs23, I appear to need:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook #'hs-minor-mode)
```

For emacs24, I appear to need:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'hs-minor-mode)
```

I'm now looking for a way to guard the commands. (I also use the `emacs-nox` variants, if it matters).

How can I add both commands to my `~/emacs` so I can copy/paste without worrying about versions?

Comment: AFAICT the `c-mode-common-hook` version should work just as well in Emacs-24 (or 25 for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know what `guarding` or `guard` means in the context of programming because I am just a hobbyist, but the following code snippet is a method of programmatically distinguishing between `emacs-major-version`:

```lisp
(cond
  ((= emacs-major-version 23)
    (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook #'hs-minor-mode))
  ((= emacs-major-version 24)
    (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'hs-minor-mode))
  (t
    (message "The catch-all condition has not been set for hs-minor-mode.")))
```

Comment: My bad... I was borrowing a C/C++ term. I removed the sentence on it because I did not think non-C/C++ programmers would understand a definition in terms of defines and preprocessor macros.

Comment: This produces an error under Debian 8: *"Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading '/root/.emacs': End of file during parsing: /root/.emacs \r\n\r\n To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the cause of the error in your initialization file. Start Emacs with the '--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace."*

Comment: @jww -- Whenever you see an error that says `End of file during parsing`, it usually means that you forgot a parentheses or a double-quote.  For example, if you copy the entire example in the answer above, there will be no error.  But, if you accidentally fail to copy one of the closing parentheses at the very end of the example, then you will encounter the error you received.  As a matter of error checking practice, I find it useful to always check whatever section I am working on to make sure the ending parentheses matches the beginning parentheses before moving on to the next project.

Comment: @jww -- I also find the built-in function `M-x check-parens` to be extremely valuable -- it moves the point to the general section of the open file that has the problem, or leaves point where it is if there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally better (more precise) to test for the existence of a function or variable than to test `emacs-major-version`.

```el
(add-hook (if (boundp 'prog-mode-hook) 'prog-mode-hook 'c-mode-common-hook)
          #'hs-minor-mode)
```